# Groovy sort list based off another list

Tags: list, sorting, grails, groovy

I have an array of objects that I want to sort based off the following list:

```
days = ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']

def i = 0

schedule.shifts.each {
    println it.dayOfWeek
    println days[i]
    if (it.dayOfWeek == days[i]) {
        shifts.add(it)
    }
}
```

I have tried wrapping this in a while loop and increment i in different spots, but I guess I cant seem to think about how it should be. (keep getting stuck in infinite loops). Can someone help me get this right? Ive been stuck for awhile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sort method allows you to specify the property you want to sort on.  In this case, it would be the index of the day in the days list.  Try something like this:

```
schedule.shifts.sort { shift -> days.indexOf(shift.dayOfWeek) }
```

Comment: Did not know I could do this. awesome! thanks